# 6g: No such file or directory - Building Go packages with `gomake` on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, go

I have two `.go` files, `numbers.go` and `numbers_test.go` and I want to build and execute the tests as per the [creating a new package tutorial](http://go.googlecode.com/hg/doc/code.html) (scroll down for details on the files.)  All files are in the same directory.

When I navigate to that directory in Terminal and type `gomake` I get this:

```
6g  -o _go_.6 numbers.go
make: 6g: No such file or directory
make: *** [_go_.6] Error 1
```

This error is saying that it cannot find `numbers.go`.  If I manually execute this line (without moving directory):

```
6g  -o _go_.6 numbers.go
```

it successfully creates the `_go_.6` file.  So why can't `gomake` find the file?

Here are the files I am using:

`numbers.go` looks like this:

```
package numbers

func Double(i int) int {
  return i * 2
}
```

`numbers_test.go` looks like this:

```
package numbers

import (
    "testing"
)

type doubleTest struct {
    in, out int
}

var doubleTests = []doubleTest{
    doubleTest{1, 2},
    doubleTest{2, 4},
    doubleTest{-5, -10},
}

func TestDouble(t *testing.T) {
    for _, dt := range doubleTests {
        v := Double(dt.in)
        if v != dt.out {
            t.Errorf("Double(%d) = %d, want %d.", dt.in, v, dt.out)
        }
    }
}
```

and finally, my `Makefile` looks like this:

```
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.inc

TARG=numbers
GOFILES=\
    numbers.go

include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't say that it can't find `numbers.go` - it's saying that it can't find `6g`. In your Makefile, try putting the path to `6g` in your PATH, as well as any other Go-specific environment variables.

Comment: Thanks - and good point.  After correctly adding the path in my `~/.bash_profile` file it just worked.